# Maximo: Save a dynamic query?

Tags: select, expression, where-clause, maximo, dynamic-variables

In Maximo 7.6.1.1, I can run a query on work orders with this WHERE clause: `reportedby = :user`:

[image]

When I hit *Find* the query runs successfully; it filters the records using the **currently logged in user**.

---

However, when I go back and look at the WHERE clause, I see that the dynamic variable (`:user`) has been replaced with a **static value** (`JSMITH`).

[image]

And when I look at the `query` table in Toad, I see that the `clause` has been saved as `reportedby =  'JSMITH'`.

This is not what I want.

**How can I save a query with a dynamic variable?**

*(Oracle 12c)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the View/Manage Queries dialog to change it back. When you first run it Maximo replaces the bind variables.

[image]